# http_listener casablanca doesn't bind from a public method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, httplistener, cpprest-sdk

As title i have a client server application that works but now i try to redesign my software to be more elegant. So i created a Server class to create an http_listener and handle POST and GET method but after that it doesn't work anymore.In .h i have:

```
class Server
```

{
    public:
    Server() {}

```
Server(utility::string_t url);

pplx::task<void> open();
pplx::task<void> close();


void handle_post(web::http::http_request message);
```

private:

```
// Error handlers
static void handle_error(pplx::task<void>& t);
// HTTP listener 
web::http::experimental::listener::http_listener m_listener;
```

};

And in .c i have:

```
Server::Server(utility::string_t url) : m_listener(url)
```

{

```
m_listener.support(methods::POST, [this](http_request request){return Server::handle_post(request); });
m_listener.support(methods::GET, handle_get);
```

}

handle_get is defined in .c for test and it works but i'm not able to support POST method .
I also tried different initialization of POST method like this:

```
m_listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&Server::handle_post, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

but it doesn't work.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
m_listener.support(methods::POST, [this](http_request request){ this->handle_post(request); });
```

looks more correct. However, is `http_request` copyable? If not, you will need to `std::move` it or pass by reference.

Comment: Now It works ,could you tell me why my 2 "solutions" didn't work?
I found them in many threads on stackoverflow without success.

Comment: @kenhero I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but my first thought was that you were not passing a `this` in the first attempt.